# How can I use internal sd for ClockworkMod on a Motorola Defy?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-defy, internal-sd

I've got a Motorola Defy I want to install CyanogenMod on. I have been following these instructions: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_jordan?setlang=en

I have got as far as running ClockworkMod but when I select "choose zip from sdcard" I get the following errors.

```
E:Can't mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 (or /dev/block/mmcblk0)
(no such file or directory)
Can't mount /sdcard
```

A bit of Googling suggests that I won't be able to access my SD Card using ClockworkMod on the Motorola Defy and need to use the internal SD instead.

So what I'd like to do is put my ROM .zip files in the internal storage and have ClockworkMod access them there.

There seems to be a reference to this on the CyanogenMod wiki instructions:

> "If you boot directly to recovery and have an internal sdcard, you may
>   need to run adb shell mount /data or mount data through the recovery
>   menu before transferring."

But I don't understand what I need to do for this to happen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the recovery does not mount the internal memory by default, and you need to do so manually.

On your PC download and install [Android SDK tools](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.2-windows.exe) which gets you the ADB utility.  Reboot your phone in Recovery mode and connect it to your PC via USB cable.  Install the drivers if prompted (use drivers that ship with SDK tools under the `\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\` subfolder.)  Now run Command Prompt, navigate to where you installed the tools (e.g. `cd C:\Android SDK\sdk\platform-tools\` ) and issue the following command:

> `adb shell mount /data`

You now should be able to use the "adb push" command in Windows Command Prompt to copy files from your PC to the phone using the following syntax:

> `adb push [path-to-file-on-your-pc] /data/`

After the copy completes, you should be able to find the copied file in the Recovery's file browser.